# Can't change default worldserver port in dockers build

Tags: docker, networking, azerothcore

I installed AzerothCore successfuly on Windows 10 Pro using Docker, and it works fine locally. I was trying to make the server public so friends can connect from the internet for testing.

Since port `8085` for `worldserver` can't be forwarded on my router (probably ISP or router firmware reserving it, other ports can just fine), I tried everything to change it in conf files, literally changed it everywhere and added the overrides in the 2 `conf.dist`. Changed it in the realmlist field in `authserver` DB too. Recompiled everything: it stays `8085` no matter what (I can see it using netstats).

In more detail: I changed the port to `8086` in `\azerothcore-wotlk\docker\worldserver\etc\worldserver.conf.dist`
added the line `"WorldServerPort = 8086"` in `worldserver.conf` and `worldserver.conf.dockerdist` in the same directory.
Even changed the port in `.env.dist` in main installation directory.
Also changed the relative field in the `realmlist` entry in `authserver` database.

I rebuilt all the containers from scratch after the config modifications and recomposed them: `worldserver` port stays `8085`.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem with the help of Francesco Borzi: turned out dockers containers have their own ports exposed so I needed to change those too accordingly.
I edited the `docker-compose.yml` file in main directory, where ports for the world server container are listed, along with the usual editings of worldserver confs and authserver database entries as usual, and recomposed from scratch.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you're using docker, you only change the port redirection in docker-compose.